# how can i fix my code in order to get rid of the error that says that the object I want to instantiate is null?

Tags: unity

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class replicate : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void replicateCube(InputField T)
    {
        int H = int.Parse(T.text);


        for (int i = 0; i < H; i++)
        {

            GameObject prefab = Resources.Load("Cube") as GameObject;
            GameObject go = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
            go.transform.position = new Vector3(0, i*5, 0);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to use the debugger and see what variable is null. Then from there, dig why the object is null.

Comment: It looks like Unity isn't finding a GameObject asset called "Cube" inside a folder called "Resources" inside your game. Why it can't find it depends on what your folder structure looks like. To be answerable, you'd need to edit this question to show us what this "Cube" asset is and where it sits inside your project folder structure.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I fixed the problem.